# Is there a windows app with a preview function to recursively delete by wildcard?

Tags: windows, wildcards

I'd like to do a ... delete `*.dll` from a folder, but preview it to make sure there aren't actually any folder names I have forgotten are there that I would actually want to keep. Other possiblities:   `*svn*` or `*ReSharper*`

Is there a program that will let me preview and do a wildcard delete? preferably with a friendly UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir *.dll /S
del *.dll /S
```

If you really want to be careful:

```
del *.dll /S /P
```

Why bother with a UI?

Comment: @ChrisF - deja vu!

Comment: I get annoyed when people suggest 3rd party tools that do what the OS can do, so I'm happy when people point out what the OS can already do for them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hyppy's answer, which I agree with, I thought I would mention [**delen.exe**](http://adoxa.110mb.com/delenxrd/), which I find very handy when I want to all delete but one (or more) files.

It also has a switch (/N), which executes the command without actually doing anything, which is useful for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Recently found out, you can just do the wildcard search in windows explorer and then select all... ctrl clicking things you don't want to delete and delete that way.